# Semantic issue, when trying to integrate SneakyJoystick into cocos2d-iphone 2.0

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d-iphone 2.0 (because Tiled does't work with last cocos2d-iphone version properly), and get this in the `SneakyJoystick.h` :

```
@interface SneakyJoystick : CCNode <CCTargetedTouchDelegate> 
// semantic issue: Can't fine protocol declaration for 'CCTargetedTouchDelegate'
```

Someone faced the problem?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I noticed you mentioned Tiled. If there is some problem in cocos2d-iphone regarding Tiled maps, please make sure to report it to their bug tracker.

Comment: That dates back to cocos2d 1.x , in 2.x look for CCTouchOneByOneDelegate instead. Seems you have quite a forklift update in front of you. Updating 1.x to 2.x is almost as much work as updating 2.x to 3.x. Pick your evil, you will have to update SneakyJoystick anyways. 3.x will require that you ARC'ify it and the rest of your project.

Answer (score -1):

The protocol's name are changed

`CCTargetedTouchDelegate` now is `CCTouchOneByOneDelegate`

try this

```
@interface SneakyJoystick : CCNode <CCTouchOneByOneDelegate>
```